# Create subroutines in one workbook that work on another

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a button on one workbook that opens another macro-less workbook. `transposeDataMatrices` is the sub that will be run on the worksheets in the workbook that is opened:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
Set BEEBook = ThisWorkbook

FileSelect = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", Title:="Please select the report to import")
If FileSelect = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set ReportBook = Workbooks.Open(FileSelect)

transposeDataMatrices

End Sub
```

Within `transposeDataMatrices` is the following, heavily truncated code (`ReportBook` is a global variable for the workbook being worked on in `trasposeDataMatrices`; `cArray` is a global array):

```
Public Sub transposeDataMatrices()

ReportBook.Activate

rowCounter = finWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For ii = 1 To wsCount

    Worksheets(ii).Activate
    pullModelData (ii) ' just pulls some data, off ii worksheet in ReportBook

    ReDim indexIDArray(0 To 504) As Integer
    Dim j as Integer: j = 0
    For Each catName In cArray
        Dim totRange As Range
        Set catTitle = Worksheets(ii).UsedRange.Find(catName)

        If Not catTitle Is Nothing Then
        catTitle.Offset(2, 0).Offset(0, 1).Select
        ReportBook.Worksheets(ii).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Select
        ReportBook.Worksheets(ii).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Set totRange = Selection
        Else
        Set totRange = Cells("A1")
        EndIf
        indexIDArray(j) = j
    Next

    equipModelVersion rowCounter, indexIDArray
    rowCounter = finWkst.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Next ii

End Sub



Sub equipModelVersion(rowCounterDummy As Integer, indexArrayDummy() As String)

ReportBook.Activate
finWkst.Activate

iCol = 1:

    Set indexRange = Range(Cells(rowCounterDummy + 1, iCol), Cells(rowCounterDummy + 1 + UBound(valueArrayDummy, 1), iCol))

    Dim j As Integer: j = 0
    For I = rowCounterDummy + 1 To rowCounterDummy + 1 + UBound(valueArrayDummy, 1)
        Cells(I, iCol) = indexArrayDummy(j)
        j = j + 1
        Next

End Sub


Sub initializeWorkspace()
ReportBook.Activate
finWkst.Activate

Range("A1").Value = "IndexID"
Range("B1").Value = "ModelID"
Range("C1").Value = "UserVersion"
Range("D1").Value = "Equipment"
Range("E1").Value = "Date"

For ii = LBound(cArray) To UBound(cArray)
    Cells(1, ii + 5).Value = cArray(ii)
    Next

End Sub
```

I have two questions:

**Firstly**, when `equipModelVersion` gets run, it stores the values in the cells of the workbook on the worksheet where the button is located, rather than the workbook that is opened, in a sheet created to store the values.

How do I rectify that?

I tried activating that specific worksheet, using a with statement, and some other quick things I found on Stack Overflow, but nothing worked.

**Secondly**, when I was debugging the `transposeDataMatrices` and had it separately, the following line worked:

```
   Set totRange = Range(Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)), Selection.End(xlDown))
```

In the macro that I transferred into the workbook with the button, it no longer works, so I had to work around it with:

```
        ReportBook.Worksheets(ii).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, -1)).Select
        ReportBook.Worksheets(ii).Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Set totRange = Selection
```

Just looks bad.

Why is VBA being so dumb about it, when the code is EXACTLY IDENTICAL, but expanded?

Comment: get rid of all `.Activate` commands and just use `With` blocks to work with whichever objects you need (workbooks, sheets, etc.). Then use `.Range` or '.Cells` within the with blocks instead of just `Range` or `Cells` then it should work as needed.

Comment: I tried With ReportBook.finWkst: .Range..., in the initiateWorkspace sub, but when the debugger gets to the first .Range, it throws up a compile error, and I am out of work-arounds so I chose to stick with the explicit way, in which case, it does not throw up a warning, but it also does not do it's intended function.

Comment: Never use Activate.  The only valid purposes for Activate in VBA are 1) to show the user something and 2) you need to invoke a visual Excel method that can only work on the activated sheet and has no non-visual workaround (there are very few of these).

Answer (score 6):

VBA is not smart, it will only do what you tell it to do not what you think you told it to do.

My guess is that somewhere the `ReportBook.Worksheets(ii)` is losing focus.

It is good practice to always declare the parent when using objects.  The easy way is to declare that parent object is as a variable.

in this case:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = ReportBook.Worksheets(ii)
```

then the with the two lines in question use a `with` statment

```
with ws
    Set totRange =.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
end with
```

You should avoid using the `.select` command.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for great information on that.  Using it only dirties the code and makes it harder to find the errors.

Comment: Plus, `Select` is activation-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the link; I'll edit the select out. I'm debugging and expanding a coworker's code from a long time ago; haven't checked out all the inefficiencies.